# Array data to nested HTML

Tags: php, html, formatting

I'm having trouble converting an array into correctly nested HTML. Assuming I have an array with the following example values -

```
An, Author---Some Book
Another, Author---A Book
Another, Author---Another Book
Be, Author---Book 1
Be, Author---Book 2
No, Author---Book 1
```

How do turn that into an organised HTML like -

```
<div>
    <div class="letter">A</div>
    <div>
        <div class="author">An, Author</div>
        <div class="title">Some Book</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="author">Another, Author</div>
        <div class="title">A Book</div>
        <div class="title">Another Book</div>
    </div>
<div>
<div>
    <div class="letter">B</div>
    <div>
        <div class="author">Be, Author</div>
        <div class="title">Book 1</div>
        <div class="title">Book 2</div>
    </div>
<div>
<div>
    <div class="letter">N</div>
    <div>
        <div class="author">No, Author</div>
        <div class="title">Book 1</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

I don't have any trouble with PHP, its just I'm not sure how I would organise the data. Split into three different arrays (Letters, Authors, Books) before pulling the data back together? But then how would I associate the books (Letter->Author->Book)?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: First you need to go through some tutorial How to traverse an array php

Comment: Can you print_r your array? do you need someone to write a function for you that will split each line, sort it into letters and then output it as shown?

Comment: I know how to traverse an array using and how to explode a string. I don't have a problem with PHP. I'm just having trouble getting everything correctly nested. I think I have to move to a different data structure, I'm just not sure what that would look like.

Comment: Post code describing us the format of the array(s), we'll go from there.

Comment: The format of the array is just as above - A single dimensional array with several strings just as they look above.

Comment: I have written the code for your question. As you see, it is nothing but traversing an array, exploding a string, and some conditionals.

Comment: that's not a good semantic presentation by the way. please use ULs and LIs since what you're generating is basically a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your array is already sorted as the example:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $parts = explode("---", $array[$i]);
    $author = $parts[0];
    $book = $parts[1];
    $letter = substr($author, 0, 1);

    if (!isset($last_author) || $last_author != $author) {

        if ($i > 0 && $last_letter != $letter) {
                echo "\t</div>\n";
                echo "</div>\n";
        } else if ($i > 0) {
                echo "\t</div>\n";
        }

        if (!isset($last_letter) || $last_letter != $letter) {
            echo "<div>\n";
            echo "\t" . '<div class="letter">' . strtoupper($letter) . '</div>' . "\n";
            $last_letter = $letter;
        }

        echo "\t<div>\n";

        echo "\t\t" . '<div class="author">' . $author . '</div>' . "\n";
        echo "\t\t" . '<div class="title">' . $book . '</div>' . "\n";

        $last_author = $author;

    } else {
        echo "\t\t" . '<div class="title">' . $book . '</div>' . "\n";
    }

}

if (count($array) > 0) echo "\t</div>\n</div>";
```

**Output from your sample array:**

```
<div>
        <div class="letter">A</div>
        <div>
                <div class="author">An, Author</div>
                <div class="title">Some Book</div>
        </div>
        <div>
                <div class="author">Another, Author</div>
                <div class="title">A Book</div>
                <div class="title">Another Book</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div>
        <div class="letter">B</div>
        <div>
                <div class="author">Be, Author</div>
                <div class="title">Book 1</div>
                <div class="title">Book 2</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div>
        <div class="letter">N</div>
        <div>
                <div class="author">No, Author</div>
                <div class="title">Book 1</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats similar to something I tried before. The problem with it is that it doesn't work with multiple authors with the same first letter. The the second author that begins with 'A' isn't nested with the first with your code, its nested on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You can also produce a multidimensional array which may require less code to render:

```
$new = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    $parts = explode("---", $array[$i]);
    $author = $parts[0];
    $book = $parts[1];
    $letter = substr($author, 0, 1);

    $new[$letter][$author][] = $book;
}

foreach ($new as $letter => $authors) {

    foreach ($authors as $author => $books) {

        foreach ($books as $book) {

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got div soup there, however you parse your arrays.

Try outputting something meaningful and semantic using lists.